# Cannot connect to sql server with VBA (Run-time error (80040e14))

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am trying to connect to my Sql database and get one simple recordset out of it running this code:

```
    Sub ConnectToSQL()

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    With cnn
         .ConnectionString = "File Name=C:\inetpub\tc\TEST.udl"
         .Open
    End With

    With cmd
          .ActiveConnection = cnn
          .CommandType = xlCmdSql
          .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TEST"
    End With

    rs.Open cmd.Execute, cnn

    If Not rs.EOF Then
           Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
           rs.Close
    Else
           MsgBox "No records returned", vbCritical
    End If

    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

    End Sub
```

As a result I get the run-time error message (80040e14) What could be wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: On this one:   rs.Open cmd.Execute, cnn

Comment: Oh - it's just `rs.Open cmd`

Comment: [This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1409.how-to-create-a-sql-connection-string-for-an-application-udl-file.aspx) might help.

Comment: If you are talking about a Microsoft SQL Server then you got probably the connection string incorrect. You might want to look at this solution as a boiler-plate for your connection: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32567664/1153513

Comment: rs.Open cmd is giving me the same error.

Comment: Ralph, the thing is I want to use UDL file as my connection string and I cannot find a good example on how to do it

Comment: @ValK then you should follow the link proposed by Mat's Mug. This is a very easy and fast solution to creating **and** validating / testing `.udl` files. Clearly, there seems to be a problem with the connection string (within the UDL file) if your code does not work.

Comment: What's the actual error **message**? (not just the number)

Comment: Why dont you assign a query to variable?  I.e. strsql = "SELECT * FROM TEST" and then do rs.Open strsql, cnn

Comment: The actual error message says: Run-time error '-2147217900(80040e14)':  Automation error

Comment: VBA wont reveal you the actual error message. You need to debug the code and put message message box at different place to see where the thing is going wrong.

Comment: @Ralph Mat's post is good but there is no info on how to implement it. I was able to create the file but it still won't work

Comment: I fixed it! In .CommandText I should have only put the name of the table "TEST". Because vba would add "select * from" to my statement and it would try to run "select * from select * from test" Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to try following? 
 Please do not forget to add Tools> Refernces if necessary.

```
Sub ConnectToSQL()    
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String

     Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    ConnectionString = "File Name=C:\inetpub\tc\TEST.udl"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

     strquery = "SELECT * FROM TEST;"

    'MsgBox strquery
    rs.Open strquery, cnn

    If Not rs.EOF Then
           Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
           rs.Close
    Else
           MsgBox "No records returned", vbCritical
    End If

    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```