# How to hardcode the credentials of a tech user in a macro

Tags: sql-server, excel, macros, connection-string

I am using a macro to execute a stored procedure in a sql server which returns some data:

```
Sql = "EXEC [dbo].[p_adhoc_reporting_sre] @as_of = '"
Sql = Sql + asof + "'"

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add


With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=FRPCREDIT_Summix_fsdb;Data Source=CHRV40" _
    , _
    "18\PIN4018;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=CHR5AFC7;Use Encryption for Data=Fals" _
    , "e;Tag with column collation when possible=False"), Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array(Sql)
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

This is using the credentials of a current user to authenticate, but I would like to replace that but the credentials of a tech user. Adding User ID and Password to the connection string does not help, and continues to use the user's credentials. Removing "Integrated Security=SSPI" makes that the credentials of the tech user are being picked up, but it is unable to connect. Do I need to add something else to the connection string?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure SQL Server authentication mode is "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"; only then are you allowed to pass in username and password (without "integrated security" in the connection string). See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

Comment: You should be able to connect using SQL authentication if you remove `INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI` and add `User ID=youruser;Password=yourpassword`.  However, the SQL Server must be configured to allow SQL authentication.  If the login fails, post the exact message.  The SQL Server error log may have additional details.

Comment: In addition to what @Ruud said you must (afterwards) change the above coding to use no longer Windows authentication (as you do at the moment: `Integrated Security=SSPI`) but instead use a username and password as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560747/ado-recordset-not-staying-open-in-vba-operation-is-not-allowed-when-the-objec/32567664#32567664

Comment: I can connect using SQL authentication using MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio, so I assume the SQL server is configured to allow SQL autentication. If I remove "Integrated Security=SSPI" from the connection string and add User ID and Password I get the following error:

Comment: Run time error 1004, the query did not run, or the db table could not be opened.

Comment: And I see nothing related to this in the SQL server error log

Comment: @mque7, does the SQL server user have permissions to execute the stored procedure? Assuming error 1004 is actually due to a SQL error, the underlying SQL error is obfuscated.

Comment: Yes, I can login with the tech user using MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio and execute the stored procedure with no problem.

Comment: Just tried adding set nocount on and set nocount off and did not help. In case this is relevant, the stored proc executes a query that is partly pointing to a linked server to an oracle database. But I can execute it directly in SSMS with no problem.